# Having emailed notes to Evernote go to a specific notebook

Tags: evernote

Is there a way in Evernote to have emailed Notes go to a specific notebook that isn't the default Evernote notebook?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is [syntax explained at the Evernote Blog](http://blog.evernote.com/blog/2010/03/16/emailing-into-evernote-just-got-better/)

In the subject of the email use `@` followed by the target notebook.

This link is for the [updated KB](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#/article/23480523) for directing emailed notes to specific notebooks.